# Solve OLE DB Connection without install Data Connectivity Components

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, office-interop, office-2007

Is there a way to solve the problem of OLEDB Connection (microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine) without install [Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) while reading an excel file .

Please Advise.

Comment: what are you trying to do hear :) are you trying to get some data from excel ?

Comment: yes i read some data from excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ExcelTools = Ms.Office;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ExcelSingle
    {
        [Test]
        public void ProcessWorkbook()
        {
            string file = @"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\TestSheet.xls";
            Console.WriteLine(file);

            Excel.Application excel = null;
            Excel.Workbook wkb = null;

            try
            {
                excel = new Excel.Application();

                wkb = ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.OpenBook(excel, file);

                Excel.Worksheet sheet = wkb.Sheets["Data"] as Excel.Worksheet;

                Excel.Range range = null;

                if (sheet != null)
                    range = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);

                string A1 = String.Empty;

                if( range != null )
                    A1 = range.Text.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("A1 value: {0}", A1);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //if you need to handle stuff
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wkb != null)
                    ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.ReleaseRCM(wkb);

                if (excel != null)
                    ExcelTools.OfficeUtil.ReleaseRCM(excel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, but can i do it without change my Methodology?, i want to still using Ole Db Connection. and as well i don't want to install this component. i know it may be strange but i ask if there a way to achieve that ?